# WDDX library for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wddx

I'm aware that there is (or was?) a JS library for WDDX (wddx.js) somewhere but I couldn't find it anymore since both www.openwddx.org and wddx.org don't seem to be active now. Can anyone give me info? I'm trying out WDDX (ie. create a packet) on a jsp page and thinking of using those js functions cause it seems like a simpler approach.

It may have been asked already but resource on Javascript and WDDX are so limited so I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find them here: http://www.finwin.com/Dev/wddxsdk/2__Software_Libraries/Installation.html
<del>http://rightworker.comoj.com/2__Software_Libraries/Installation.html</del>

It says:

> This is the current distribution of the WDDX libraries available for the various platforms that support WDDX at this time. Please check back at Wddx.org often for updates.
>   Please refer to the corresponding portions of the Building Apps With WDDX and References sections of this SDK for documentation, suggestions, examples, and usage.

But be aware, the JS code is from 1999. I'm using it to deserialize wddxPackets comming from PHP and it works for me. I don't know if there are any other JS implementations and/or newer ones releases of the one above.

Comment: The domain name in the link is no more. Here is an alternative: http://www.finwin.com/Dev/wddxsdk/2__Software_Libraries/Installation.html